# java only executes the second if statement in a function but not the first one if i use the conn.isValid function

Tags: java, function

I have a Java function that is supposed to check the connection to the database. The problem is that when I call this function, the second if statment is always called, the first one is effectively never called.

```
        public static void CheckConnection() {
            if (conn == null) {
                conn = Jdbc_mysql_connection.connecttodb(null);
            } if (conn.isValid(10)) {
                System.out.println("Datenbankverbindung besteht noch");
            } else {
                conn = Jdbc_mysql_connection.connecttodb(null);
            }
        }
```

if I replace the conn.isValid(10) with a conn == null both are executed, but I can't imagine that the conn.isValid function causes the function to no longer be executed correctly.

I have tried to correct the formatting, but it seems to be correct.
With else it does not work either

```
    public static void CheckConnection()
    {
        if (conn == null)
        {
            conn = Jdbc_mysql_connection.connecttodb(null);
        }
        else {
        if (conn.isValid(10))
        {
            System.out.println("Datenbankverbindung besteht noch");
        }
        else
        {
            conn = Jdbc_mysql_connection.connecttodb(null);
        }}
    }
```

It only works when i write it like this :

```
    public static void CheckConnection()
    {
        if (conn == null)
        {
            conn = Jdbc_mysql_connection.connecttodb(null);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (conn.isValid(10))
                {
                    System.out.println("Datenbankverbindung besteht noch");
                }
                else
                {
                    conn = Jdbc_mysql_connection.connecttodb(null);
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Fehler beim Überprüfen der Datenbankverbindung: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget an `else` before the second `if`?

Comment: Your IDE has a format/prettify function, you might want to try that to see how your if & else are actually set up.

Comment: @Martheen my ide(eclipse) has a formatting function, but it did not effectively change my code).
  I had already thought of that, but unfortunately that doesn't help either. 
What still puzzles me is that the function is executed correctly as soon as I replace the conn.isvalid.

Comment: Instead of saying “works” and “does not work” please say exactly what happens (paste in exception messages and stack traces if you have them) and what you wanted to happen instead.

Comment: Also, please show us exactly what `Jdbc_mysql_connection.connecttodb(null)` does. My guess is that it’s returning `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple `if` statements they will always be called. However, whether the body of the statement will be executed or not depends on the condition.

If you do not wish to execute the remaining if statements you have to look into [guard condition](https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses)